# What does the "R + 'static" syntax mean in "F: FnOnce(&mut Resource<S>) -> R + 'static"?

Tags: syntax, rust, lifetime, rust-actix

I am trying to understand the [following code in actix-web](https://actix.rs/actix-web/actix_web/struct.App.html)

```
pub fn resource<F, R>(self, path: &str, f: F) -> App<S>
where
    F: FnOnce(&mut Resource<S>) -> R + 'static,
```

From my understanding, `resource` is a function that takes 2 parameters: a string slice and a function.

The function can be used only once and accepts a mutable reference of `Resource` with `S` inside and returns `R` for which `R` and `S` is completely arbitrary.

What is `R + static`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`R` is the return value of `f`.

If you look inside the `actix-web` [source](https://actix.rs/actix-web/src/actix_web/application.rs.html#345), you can see that this value is discarded/not used. I think this is mostly a convenience thing; rather than specifying a `()` return value, actix is making it easy by not caring what you return from your `f`.

I believe the `'static` lifetime should be read as applying to the `F` rather than the `R`. That is, the `f` (usually a closure) should have a static lifetime.

Comment: You are right about the last point. The `+` operator in this context combines multiple trait or lifetime bounds. `R` isn't a trait bound, but rather a concrete type. `FnOnce(...) -> R` on the other hand is a trait bound, and `'static` is a lifetime bound, so the two can be combined with `+`.